# Structuring a Library in SML

Tags: sml, polyml

I'm currently building a testing library in Standard ML (using Poly/ML as the interpreter). I have the following directory structure:

```
project/a.sml
project/src/b.sml
project/src/c.sml
...
```

Where `a.sml` is just a bunch of calls to use

```
use "src/b.sml"
use "src/c.sml"
...
```

`b.sml`, `c.sml` etc. are all structure definitions like this

```
structure ComponentX
struct
...
end
```

which form nice, logically separated components of the library. I sometimes also create one module in one file, and then introduce a substructure within the same module in another file.

I can then use the testing library fine within the root directory of the project, by calling `use "a.sml"`.

However, I can't seem to be able to use the code outside of its own directory, which is a bit of an issue. For example, say I'm in the parent directory of `project`. If I then call `use "project/a.sml"`, the subsequent calls to `use "src/x.sml"` try to find a `src` directory in the parent (which doesn't exist).

Is there some way to do a relative `use`, or is there a better way to structure this altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `use` function itself in Poly/ML doesn't change the path when it is used recursively.  You will need to change the path within the sub-directory explicitly using `OS.FileSys.chDir`.  `use` is just a function so you could redefine it if you wanted.  The `OS.Path` and `OS.FileSys` structures could be useful.

An alternative is to reorganise your code to make use of `PolyML.make`.  You would have to rename your files to match the name of the structure that each file contains e.g. ComponentX.sml would contain structure ComponentX. For more on this see [polyml.org/documentation/Reference/PolyMLMake.html](http://polyml.org/documentation/Reference/PolyMLMake.html) or a [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315827/using-poly-ml-to-build-projects-with-nested-directory-structures/29331793#29331793) about Poly/ML with nested directory structures.