# How to access a library in Poly/ML on Windows?

Tags: sml, polyml

I have installed Poly/ML from the "PolyML5.6-64bit.msi" installer; I can start the REPL by clicking it in the Start menu; but I don't know how to access any libraries from it? I tried doing `use "something"`, but it results in an error like below:

```
> use "Math";
Exception-
   Io
     {cause = SysErr ("No such file or directory", SOME ENOENT), function =
      "TextIO.openIn", name = "Math"} raised
```

Similar for `use "Basis"` or `use "Windows"`.

Please note that I'm a total newbie to SML; I seem to have found the `use` command in some generic SML tutorial, don't know if I'm using it correctly at all :/

*edit:* Also, the target installation directory seems to contain only the following three binary files, not sure if there should be some sources there, or not:

```
C:\Program Files\Poly ML>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is CENS-ORED

 Directory of C:\Program Files\Poly ML

26.02.2016  00:03    <DIR>          .
26.02.2016  00:03    <DIR>          ..
25.01.2016  14:22           681 472 PolyLib.dll
25.01.2016  14:23         8 182 784 PolyML.exe
25.01.2016  14:22            20 480 PolyPerf.dll
               3 File(s)      8 884 736 bytes
```

---

*edit2:* Hmmm... from some further browsing, I'm starting to think that apparently Poly/ML seems to be [used by most people purely from within](http://sketis.net/2014/isabellepide-as-ide-for-standard-ml) the ["Isabelle IDE"](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/)? so maybe if I install this one, all will work out of the box? I'll try, but still the original question remains open for now.

*edit3:* Uhhh, the Isabelle IDE is weird, specifically no idea how to "Run" an SML file opened in it anyways :/ probably going to uninstall (i.e. delete?) it in this situation, also given the fact that I got the answer to the original question already now.

Comment: In Windows I like to use textpad ( http://textpad.com/index.html ) for SML. It isn't an IDE but you can download a textpad sml syntax definition file and get useful syntax highlighting for your code. Typing in the full path-name in a `use` command is annoying. What I tend to do is have a comment at the top of my files which looks something like `(* use "C:/Programs/SML/foo.sml"; *)` and then paste the body of the comment into the SML REPL when I want to load the definitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Poly/ML on Linux, not Windows. But I'm almost certain that what follows is also true on Windows.

You don't need to use the `use` function to load the Basis Library's modules, which are already in the top-level environment when you start the Poly/ML REPL. For example:

```
lolcathost% poly
Poly/ML 5.6 Release
> structure M = Math;
structure M: MATH
> M.pi;
val it = 3.141592654: real
>
```

You use the `use` function to load your own code. The argument must be either an absolute path, or a path relative to the current working directory. <strike>I have no idea if it's possible to change the current working directory in the REPL.</strike> [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30423680/46571) to see how to change the current working directory, if you need it.

Also, for larger projects, you might want to use [Poly/ML's make system](http://polyml.org/documentation/Reference/PolyMLMake.html) rather than `use`.

---

In response to your comment:

The module [PolyML.Compiler](http://polyml.org/documentation/Reference/PolyMLCompiler.html) provides functions to retrieve the *names* of the existing [values](http://polyml.org/documentation/Reference/PolyMLCompiler.html#valueNames), [types](http://polyml.org/documentation/Reference/PolyMLCompiler.html#typeNames), [signatures](http://polyml.org/documentation/Reference/PolyMLCompiler.html#structureNames), [structures](http://polyml.org/documentation/Reference/PolyMLCompiler.html#structureNames) and [functors](http://polyml.org/documentation/Reference/PolyMLCompiler.html#functorNames) in the top-level environment.

However, the names alone aren't terribly useful. Here are some tricks to get the REPL to tell you more.

**Types:** Say you want to know what the constructors of `list` are.

```
> datatype foo = datatype list;
datatype 'a foo = :: of 'a * 'a foo | nil
>
```

Or how the type synonym `StringCvt.reader` is defined.

```
> datatype foo = datatype StringCvt.reader;
type ('a, 'b) foo = 'b -> ('a * 'b) option
>
```

Of course, if you use this trick on an abstract data type, you won't get much information:

```
> datatype foo = datatype string;
eqtype foo
>
```

**Structures:** Say you want to know what the value and type components of the structure `Byte` are.

```
> structure Foo = struct open Byte end;
structure Foo:
  sig
    val byteToChar: Word8.word -> char
    val bytesToString: Word8Vector.vector -> string
    val charToByte: char -> Word8.word
    val packString: Word8Array.array * int * substring -> unit
    val stringToBytes: string -> Word8Vector.vector
    val unpackString: Word8ArraySlice.slice -> string
    val unpackStringVec: Word8VectorSlice.slice -> string
  end
>
```

**Signatures:** Say you want to know what the value and type components of the signature `BYTE` are.

```
> functor Foo (X : BYTE) = struct open X end;
functor Foo (X: BYTE): 
  sig
    val byteToChar: Word8.word -> char
    val bytesToString: Word8Vector.vector -> string
    val charToByte: char -> Word8.word
    val packString: Word8Array.array * int * substring -> unit
    val stringToBytes: string -> Word8Vector.vector
    val unpackString: Word8ArraySlice.slice -> string
    val unpackStringVec: Word8VectorSlice.slice -> string
  end
>
```

Comment: Ahhhh, it works indeed, thanks a lot! For the record, it works for `structure W = Windows;` too, and to verify a "negative case", `structure Q = Qwerty;` fails with an error.  

With that said, an extra question if I may: is it possible to list all "globally available modules/structures", and/or their contents, i.e. for example what's there in "Math"?

Comment: @akavel: The Standard Basis Library is documented [here](http://sml-family.org/Basis/). Another quick way to check the contents of a module is to use `structure M = struct open Math end;`.

Comment: The trick works magnificiently, thanks! :) Still, is it possible to use it to view the "global top-level environment"? (including the list of all available structs?)

Comment: Thanks! So to print e.g. all structures, I understand I can do something like: `print(String.concatWith "\n" (PolyML.Compiler.structureNames()))` (though randomly sorted)

Comment: @akavel: Yes, pretty much.